# Single QuerySet to select some records or all records

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

I have a form with ModelChoiceField field which can be empty (assuming "All selected") or has a certain value.

What is the best way to create a single QuerySet which select **all** records or **some** records without using **if-else** statement?

Currently I am using something like this:

**Form**:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    operators = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=EpayOperators.objects.all(),
        label="Choose operator", 
        empty_label="All",
        required=False)
    ...
```

**View**:

```
# Any security and validation checks are ommited
...
if request.POST.get('operators'):
    # Some operator was selected
    payments = Transactions.objects.filter(date=my_date, sum=my_sum, operator=MyForm.cleaned_data['operators'])
else:
    # None selected, display all operators
    payments = Transactions.objects.filter(date=my_date, sum=my_sum)
```

I feeling that this is not the pythonic way to do it: to use if-else with two separates queries.

Is there any way to create a single, versatile, query?

What is the proper way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
filter_args = {}
filter_args['date'] = my_date
filter_args['sum'] = my_sum
if request.POST.get('operators'):
    filter_args['operator'] = MyForm.cleaned_data['operators']
payments = Transactions.objects.filter(**filter_args)
```

However your code is clear as it is so I'm not sure this improves your code.

Comment: Thank you Simeon. My problem is that both queries use **filter()** and they have identical fields except **operator**. I have updated the question's code.

Comment: @Lufa: that doesn't make a difference as you can populate `filter_args` accordingly. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Got it. **kwargs look much more elegant. Tnx!